# Insert and sort linkedlist node

Tags: java

```
    @Override
```

I need to sort the words in their frequency order from most frequent word to the least frequent. If two words have the same frequency they are sorted in alphabetical order. I'm not sure how to do the insert method that combines all the things I have to do. I've made attempts to do the add count part and the frequency ordering part, and I have no idea how to sort the same frequencies alphabetically. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Which writing system's alphabet for which language? (Basic Latin A-Z for English, I suppose.) Also, note that in some cases some letters are not part of the alphabet and some words include non-letter characters. It's probably better to skip the idea of an alphabet. Just use an established [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). And, since you are probably using String to hold your words, you are using the Unicode character set. So, you should [normalize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html) first.

Answer (score 0):

If each word is a `String`, you can simply convert the word to lowercase (or uppercase, doesn't matter which), and then use the `compareTo` method. I believe if the string comes before in lexicographical order (think of it as a dictionary), then `compareTo` should return a negative value. If it comes after, it returns positive. If it's the same word, it returns zero.

So:

```
String a = "hello";
String b = "hawk";
int c = a.compareTo(b);
```

c should contain a positive value, as "hello" comes after "hawk" alphabetically.

Also notice that `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` should be used, because `compareTo()` uses the ASCII code, and ASCII uppercase letters come before lowercase letters ('A' comes before 'a').